# How to write a for loop where the index is used to find a value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, error-handling

I have this SpatialPointsDataframe, with a column named "year".

```
"Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola"), a0 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), idstd = c(95087, 95311, 95060, 95410, 95380, 
95238), wt = c(2.25999999046326, 1.76999998092651, 2.13000011444092, 
2.20000004768372, 1.64999997615814, 1.78999996185303), stra_sector = c("Other Manufacturing", 
"Retail", "Food", "Other Services", "Other Services", "Retail"
), size = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), isic = c(20L, NA, 15L, NA, 
NA, NA), a2x = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), city = c("Luanda", 
"Benguela", "Luanda", "Huambo", "Luanda", "Luanda"), a3 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), a3b = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a3c = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a5 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), size_ch = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), a7 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), a7a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a7c = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a8 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), a8a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a9 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a10 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), a11 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a11a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a14 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), a14d = c(12L, 24L, 11L, 14L, 7L, 5L), a14h = c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 12L), a14m = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), a14min = c(25L, 
15L, 35L, 15L, 30L, 24L), a14y = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a15 = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), a15d = c(12L, 24L, 11L, 14L, 7L, 5L), a15h = c(3L, 
5L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 1L), a15m = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), a15min = c(30L, 
4L, 35L, 0L, 30L, 32L), a15y = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a16 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1), a17 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), a18 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L
), a19h = c(3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), a19min = c(45L, 50L, NA, 
NA, NA, 30L), a20dend = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a20dstart = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), a20mend = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a20mstart = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a20yend = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), a20ystart = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), legal_status = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L), b1x = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), ownership_pvt_domestic = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 0, 100), ownership_pvt_foreign = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
100, 0), ownership_public = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ownership_other = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), b3 = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), ownership_female = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), b4a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), b4a_cat = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), established_year = c(2001L, 1991L, 2005L, 2000L, 2002L, 2003L
), established_employment = c(2L, 23L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 20L), established_registered = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), established_registered_year = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), established_tmanagement_years = c(8, 
9, 5, 6, 15, 2), established_tmanagament_female = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), b8 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), b8x = c("", "", "", "", "", 
""), c1 = c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), c2 = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 
NA), c3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), c4 = c(NA, NA, 30L, NA, 
NA, NA), c5 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), c6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), c7 = c(5, 2, 5, 2, 20, NA), c8 = c(24, 48, 48, 48, 10, 
NA), c8a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c8b = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c9a = c(20, 5, 2, 0, NA, NA), 
    c9b = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), c10 = c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), c11 = c(NA, NA, 
    2, NA, NA, NA), c12 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), c13 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), c14 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c15 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA
    ), c16 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c17 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c18 = c(NA, NA, 0.100000001490116, 
    NA, NA, NA), c19 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), c20 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 30L, NA), c21 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA), c22a = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), c22b = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), c23 = c(NA, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), c24a = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), c24b = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c24c = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c24d = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), c25 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c26 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), c27 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), c29 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), c30a = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L), c30b = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), d1a1a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), sales_mainproduct = c("Janelas", 
    "", "Pao", "", "", ""), isic4 = c(2022L, NA, 1541L, NA, NA, 
    NA), sales_mainproduct_share = c(50, NA, 100, NA, NA, NA), 
    sales_total = c(3300000, 2.9e+07, 3580000, 4e+06, 1e+07, 
    28822000), sales_totalx = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), sales_total3y = c(50, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 100), sales_national = c(50, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), sales_indexp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), d4 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), d5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), d5a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), d6 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), d7 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), sales_direxp = c(2001L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d9 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), d10 = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA), d10a = c(0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA), d11 = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA), d12a = c(100, NA, 70, NA, NA, NA), d12b = c(0, 
    NA, 30, NA, NA, NA), sales_yearexport = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
    NA, NA), d14 = c(NA, NA, 30L, NA, NA, NA), d15 = c(NA, NA, 
    30L, NA, NA, NA), d15a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), d16 = c(7L, 15L, 
    15L, 0L, 2L, 4L), d17 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), d30a = c(0L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 0L), d30b = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L), sales_dirimp = c(1L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), e2 = c(1L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA), comp_market = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), e3 = c(2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), e4 = c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 
    NA, NA), comp_number = c(2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), e11 = c(NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), e30 = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L), comp_license = c(40, 
    NA, 90, NA, NA, NA), capacity_percent = c(48, NA, 60, NA, 
    NA, NA), capacity_hours = c(0, 100, 90, 100, 0, 100), land_owned = c(100, 
    0, 10, 0, 100, 0), land_rented = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), g2 = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), g3 = c(NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA), g4 = c(NA, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), g5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), g5a = c(NA, 320, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), g5b = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), g5bx = c("", 
    NA, "", "", "", NA), land_leased = c(NA, 100L, NA, NA, NA, 
    100L), land_b_owned = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0), land_b_rented = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), g7 = c(NA, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L), g8 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), g8a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), g30a = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), g30b = c(NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 0L), h1 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), h2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), h3x = c("", "", "", "", "", ""
    ), h4x = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), h5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), h6x = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), h8 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), h30 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), i1 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), i2a = c(NA, 
    5, NA, NA, NA, NA), i2b = c(NA, NA, 56000, NA, NA, NA), i3 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), i4a = c(6, 5.5, 3, NA, NA, NA), i4b = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), i30 = c(4L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), j1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), j1a = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L), j2 = c(5, 5, 1, 5, 15, 1), j3 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), j4 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 3L, 6L, NA), j5 = c(NA, 2L, 
    NA, 2L, 2L, NA), j6 = c(6, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0), j6a = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), j7a = c(4, 0, 2, 0, NA, 0), j7b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 16000, 
    NA), j8 = c(50, 100, 10, 100, 10, 25), j9 = c(50, 100, 50, 
    100, 10, 75), j10 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), j11 = c(NA, 
    8L, NA, NA, NA, NA), j12 = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), j13 = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), j14 = c(NA, 8L, NA, 7L, NA, NA), j15 = c(NA, 
    2L, NA, 2L, NA, NA), j30a = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L), j30b = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), j30c = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L), j30d = c("Obstï¿½Culo Menor", 
    "Ningï¿½N Obstï¿½Culo", "Obstï¿½Culo Moderado", "Ningï¿½N Obstï¿½Culo", 
    "Ningï¿½N Obstï¿½Culo", "Ningï¿½N Obstï¿½Culo"), j30e = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), j30f = c(4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L), j30g = c(NA, 
    "No Obstacle", NA, NA, NA, "No Obstacle"), j30h = c(NA, "No Obstacle", 
    NA, NA, NA, "No Obstacle"), k1a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20), k1b = c(100, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 20), k1c = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k1d = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), k1e = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 60L), k2a = c(50, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 25), k2b = c(50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 25), k2c = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 50), land_b_leased = c(80, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    NA), k3b = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), finance_wc_internal = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA), k3c = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), k3d = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA), finance_wc_banks = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    NA), finance_wc_nonbanks = c(20, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA), k3g = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA), k3h = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA), finance_wc_credits = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k3hdx = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), k3i = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), finance_wc_others = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), k4b = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), finance_purchased = c(50, NA, 100, NA, 100, 
    NA), k5b = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), finance_purchased_machinery = c(0, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, NA), k5bc1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k5c = c(0L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0L, NA), k5d = c(50L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), finance_purchased_land = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), finance_fa_internal = c(0, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, NA), k5g = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), k5h = c(0L, NA, 
    0L, NA, 0L, NA), k5hd = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k5hdJx = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), k5hdej = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), finance_fa_equity = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), finance_fa_bank = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), k5j = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, NA), k5k = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k6 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), k7 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), k8 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), k9 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k10 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k11 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k12 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k13 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k14a = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k14b = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k14c = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k14d = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k14e = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k15 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k15a = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k15b = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k15c = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), k15d = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k16 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), k17 = c(6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
    6L, 1L), k18 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k18a = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), k19 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k20 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), k20a = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), k20a1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), k21 = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), k30 = c(0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L), finance_fa_nonbank = c(5L, 
    28L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 20L), finance_fa_credits = c(2L, 28L, NA, 
    8L, 5L, NA), finance_fa_others = c(5L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA
    ), employment_ft_total = c(0L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_total3y = c(5L, 
    NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA), l4a1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), l4a2 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), employment_ft_production = c(0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    employment_ft_nonproduction = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), employment_ft_skilled = c(0L, 
    NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_unskilled = c(0L, NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_female = c(0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L), employment_ft_femaleprod = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), l7 = c(NA, 
    NA, 0.100000001490116, NA, 0, NA), employment_ft_femalenonprod = c(NA, 
    NA, 12, NA, 2, NA), l9 = c(3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_temporary = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), employment_ft_temporary2 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), employment_ft_temporary3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), employment_ft_education = c(2L, 
    NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_education2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), l11a1 = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), employment_ft_education3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), l11b1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), l12 = c(0, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 6), l13 = c("No Afectï¿½", "No Afectï¿½", "No Afectï¿½", 
    "No Afectï¿½", "No Afectï¿½", "No Afectï¿½"), l14a = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), l14b = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), employment_ft_training = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), employment_ft_training2 = c(0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), m1d = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), m1a = c(4L, 15L, 
    12L, 8L, 8L, 4L), n1a = c(100, NA, 85, NA, NA, NA), n1b = c(0, 
    NA, 15, NA, NA, NA), n1c = c(0L, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA), employment_ft_training3 = c(1250000, 
    8e+06, 1580000, 8e+05, 750000, 2800000), employment_regulation1 = c(117000, 
    42000, 50000, 45000, 130000, 145750), n2c = c(81000, 83000, 
    146000, 25000, 90000, 150000), n2d = c(120000, 0, 32000, 
    0, 144000, 0), employment_regulation2 = c(1300000, NA, 1275340, 
    NA, NA, NA), performance_cost_labor = c(0, NA, 60000, NA, 
    NA, NA), n2g = c(0, NA, 46473, NA, NA, NA), n2h = c(0, NA, 
    32000, NA, NA, NA), performance_cost_electricity = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), performance_cost_fingood = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), n2p = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), n2ra = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), n2rb = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), performance_cost_intergood = c(1200000, 
    25500000, NA, 2900000, NA, NA), n4a = c(20000, NA, 15000, 
    NA, NA, NA), n4b = c(NA, NA, 25000, NA, NA, NA), performance_cost_fuel = c(16000, 
    0, 186243, 0, 2e+05, 0), perfomrance_cost_others = c(0, 0, 
    134716, 0, 0, 0), n5c = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), n5d = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), performance_assets_machinery = c(0, 
    NA, 205385, NA, NA, NA), performance_assets_land = c(16000, 
    NA, 186000, NA, NA, NA), performance_assets_machinery2 = c(50000, 
    NA, 9e+06, NA, NA, NA), performance_assets_land2 = c(12000, 
    NA, 2e+06, NA, NA, NA), h7a = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L), 
    h7b = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), h7c = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 1L), h7d = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L), h7x = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", ""), a20d = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a20m = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), a20y = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), r1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), r2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), r3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), r4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), r5 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), r6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), r7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), r8 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), r9 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), r10 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), r11 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), l9b1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), a6c = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), b3a = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), a7dx_num = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), a15a2_check = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), region = c("AFR", "AFR", "AFR", "AFR", "AFR", "AFR"), 
    strata = c(92L, 12L, 90L, 51L, 94L, 93L), methodologyx = c("Global", 
    "Global", "Global", "Global", "Global", "Global"), sector_MS = c("Manufacturing", 
    "Services", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Services", "Services"
    ), sample = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), size_num = c(5, 28, 
    14, 8, 5.16666650772095, 20), strata_all = c(14827L, 2983L, 
    14681L, 10820L, 14969L, 14899L), wt_rs = c(0.00270477286539972, 
    0.00211833976209164, 0.00254918867722154, 0.0026329648680985, 
    0.00197472353465855, 0.00214227568358183), year = c(2006L, 
    2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L), oc_lat = c(-8.8272699, 
    -12.9104657, -8.8272699, -12.6076318, -8.8272699, -8.8272699
    ), oc_lng = c(13.2439512, 14.0356608, 13.2439512, 15.7411039, 
    13.2439512, 13.2439512), oc_formatted = c("Luanda, Municipality of Luanda, Angola", 
    "Benguela, Angola", "Luanda, Municipality of Luanda, Angola", 
    "Huambo, Angola", "Luanda, Municipality of Luanda, Angola", 
    "Luanda, Municipality of Luanda, Angola")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"), coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(13.2439512, 
14.0356608, 13.2439512, 15.7411039, 13.2439512, 13.2439512, -8.8272699, 
-12.9104657, -8.8272699, -12.6076318, -8.8272699, -8.8272699), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"))), bbox = structure(c(13.2439512, 
-12.9104657, 15.7411039, -8.8272699), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("coords.x1", "coords.x2"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
    projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

I want to write a for loop in order to select only rows with specific years.

```
for (i in c(2006,2010)) {
  paste("WBES_angola_",i) <- WBES[WBES$country=="Angola" & WBES$year== i, c(1,3,359,360)]
  
}
```

The "year" column is of class "integer" and the index i is of class "numeric. However, R returns me an error of this type:

```
Error in paste("WBES_angola_", i) <- WBES[WBES$country == "Angola" & WBES$year ==  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot assign anything to `paste("WBES_angola_", i)`, this is not a valid variable.

Comment: Also, when you have a very 'large' data frame, it might be a good idea to use ```head()``` , or select the relevant columns. Or you can create another dummy data frame with the same ```class```.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you perhaps reverse the order of operations, did you mean `WBES[WBES$country=="Angola" & WBES$year== i, c(1,3,359,360)] <- paste("WBES_angola_",i)`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I am trying to getting it around with `WBES_angola <- list()` and `WBES_angola[[paste0("WBES_angola_",i)]] <- WBES[WBES$country=="Angola" & WBES$year== i, c(1,3,359,360)]`

Comment: You can use `x <- WBES[WBES$country=="Angola" & WBES$year== i, c(1,3,359,360)]; assign(paste0("WBES_angola_",i), x)`.

Comment: Ok. What if I want to apply a further function to each of the two elements created with `assign`?